# ASP.NET returns "NullReferenceException" on cached page

Tags: asp.net, outputcache

I used the cache system on the content.aspx page like below:

```
<%@ OutputCache Duration="300" VaryByParam="id;mediaId" %>
```

When the new page is requested, I get

> NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object

The same problem that explains **[This](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/831382)** page

The above page explains a problem in ASP.NET 1.1, but my page compiles under Visual Studio 2008 and ASP.NET 3.5.

**Note:** I use URL Rewrite API on my site to:
mydomain.com/news/123 -> mydomain.com/content.aspx?id=123

Please share me your experience about this problem

Edited: The Page error is

> Server Error in '/' Application. Object reference not set to an
>   instance of an object. Description: An unhandled exception occurred
>   during the execution of the current web request. Please review the
>   stack trace for more information about the error and where it
>   originated in the code.
>
> Exception Details: System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not
>   set to an instance of an object.
>
> Source Error:
>
> An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the
>   current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of
>   the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.
>
> Stack Trace:
>
> [NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an
>   object.]    AyandeNews.Main.Page_Load(Object sender, EventArgs e) +629
>   System.Web.Util.CalliHelper.EventArgFunctionCaller(IntPtr fp, Object
>   o, Object t, EventArgs e) +14
>   System.Web.Util.CalliEventHandlerDelegateProxy.Callback(Object sender,
>   EventArgs e) +35    System.Web.UI.Control.OnLoad(EventArgs e) +99
>   AyandeNews.PSBaseMasterPage.OnLoad(EventArgs e) +37
>   System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive() +50
>   System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive() +141
>   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean
>   includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)
>   +627
>
> Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:2.0.50727.3082;
>   ASP.NET Version:2.0.50727.3082

Comment: I add location="server" to page directive and now the error seems occur less than before. but there is the problem yet.

Comment: default page has no error but error occurs in pages that have parameters. I think error occurs when the expiration time is out. in this time, after viewing the error page, you must refresh to view the page.